# initiate call by clicking link on a page on mobile web browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsp, ionic-framework

I am working on project where on clicking a link the phone call gets initiated ,without any prompt from android or ios phones. I am trying to achieve this using angular using the below code but this isn't working:

```
<a class="button" ng-click="phonecallTab(Phonenumber)"></a>
```

and code:

```
$scope.phonecallTab = function ( phonenumber ) {
    var call = "tel:" + phonenumber;
    alert('Calling ' + call ); //Alert notification is displayed on mobile, so function is triggered correctly!
    document.location.href = call;
}
```

I googled and found that the below should be added to the `config.xml` to achieve this, but as I am using apache and do not want an app, what should I do to achieve this? Where on clicking the link the call gets initiated without any confirm dialog as on IOS or landing on the dialer screen as in Android?

```
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes" />
<access origin="mailto:*" launch-external="yes" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't. I would have put that alert check in the OS, and I think android and iOS does the same.
I'm thinking of the UX to suddenly be calling someone without choosing it.
But I might be wrong, like the meta tags or other can change that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is worked for me , check it once 
In your HTML page

```
<a ng-click="callMobile(number)" href="#" >{{number}}</a>
```

In your controller the code will be

```
$scope.callMobile = function(number){
    console.log('callMobile function got called');
    console.log('number: ' + number)
     window.open('tel:' + number, '_system');
  }
```

Reply back if you have any queries